# How to manage local groups on a remote machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, file-sharing, user-management, user-permissions

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine that exists as part of a domain, but I have no permissions to modify Domain Users, Domain Groups, Group Policies, etc. I have a few file shares on this machine and I allow access to certain Domain Users. I do this through Local Groups on the machine. I do not work on this machine regularly so it is annoying to connect to the machine to manage users.

In the past, I've used `PsExec` as well as `Microsoft Management Console` with a remote machine. Both of these options are quite clunky and slow - even for single user adds and removes.

Now, I'd like to make it easier to add new users to specific local groups, and to remove certain users from all local groups when needed. Is there a suggested way to do this? I've seen a few PowerShell scripts and BAT files that will do the job - but it seems a bit messy and cumbersome. Is there some awesome feature or utility I'm completely overlooking - or should I start writing my own?

Comment: If you have user management access on that machine, you might be able to connect remotely to it via computer management from a remote machine and then just manage it like you would if you logged into it.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to the machine is the only way to manage local groups on the machine, irrespective of the method of management (powershell, MMC, vbscript...etc) If the machine is in a domain then you should have a local group that contains a domain global group that contains the AD accounts that you want.